# Google Or-Tools manipulating variables before solver

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, or-tools, constraint-programming

I am new to OR-Tools and I am trying to solve an optimisation problem with 12 variables (masochism, I know).

Each variable represents how much time each person (out of 2) should work on a particular device model (out of 2) each day (out of 3). New devices arrive each day and there are many devices in the backlog that arrived several days ago. Each device needs to be processed within 2 days of arrival.

Basically, I want to maximise the proportion of devices that get processed within 2 days of arrival out of the total number of devices (some of them take more than 2 days because there are not enough people and time).

I have a table like this that shows which device model arrives when (day `-2` means it arrived the day before yesterday, day `0` is today):

```
    item    arrival day
0   ITEM 1  -2
1   ITEM 1  -2
2   ITEM 1  -2
3   ITEM 1  -2
18  ITEM 1  2
17  ITEM 1  1
16  ITEM 1  1
14  ITEM 1  0
...
```

My goal is to work out how many days each device takes to be processed, so I want to add a column to this table that shows on which day that item gets processed, then another column showing how many days that took ('age'), then another showing if it took more than 2 days:

```
    item    arrival day  processed date  age  success (within 2 days)?
0   ITEM 1  -2               0            2           1
1   ITEM 1  -2               0            2           1
2   ITEM 1  -2               1            3           0
3   ITEM 1  -2               2            4           0
18  ITEM 1  2                2            0           1
17  ITEM 1  1                2            1           1
16  ITEM 1  1                2            1           1
14  ITEM 1  0                1            1           1
```

In this example there are 6 devices that were processed within 2 days out of 8 total, so the success rate is 6/8. I want to maximise this success rate.

I don't know how to create the objective function for this in OR-Tools. I tried to recreate this table as a dataframe and then have the objective function as the sum of the 1's in the last column, but the `processed date` column depends on the variables in the optimisation model, so I can't create this table before the model is solved.

I tried this (where `a10, b10, a11, b11, a12, b12` are my variables and `s1a, s1b` are constants). ***What doesn't work:***

```
# define variables
a10 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'a10')
a11 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'a11')
a12 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'a12')
b10 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'b10')
b11 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'b11')
b12 = model.NewIntVar(0, 8, 'b12')

# to create the dataframe with `item` and `arrival day` columns
total_demand = [backlog, incoming]
total_demand = pd.concat(total_demand, ignore_index=True)
total_demand = total_demand.sort_values('item')


# then an attempt to create the `processed date` column
item1_repair_day = []
count = 0

for i in range(0, (a10*s1a + b10*s1b + a11*s1a + b11*s1b + a12*s1a + b12*s1b)):
    if a10*s1a + b10*s1b > count:
        item1_repair_day.append(0)
        count += 1
    else:
        if a11*s1a + b11*s1b > count:
            item1_repair_day.append(1)
            count += 1
        else:
            if a12*s1a + b12*s1b > count:
                item1_repair_day.append(2)
                count += 1
            else:
                print("No item 1's were processed on Day 0, Day 1, and Day 2")

total_demand['repair day'] = item1_repair_day
```

I could then work out the `age` and `success` columns from there and get the objective function, but the code above doesn't work.

***What I want as my objective function***

```
objective_function = total_demand['success'].sum()

model.Maximize(objective_function)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

this makes no sense:

```
for i in range(0, (a10*s1a + b10*s1b + a11*s1a + b11*s1b + a12*s1a + b12*s1b)):
```

`a10` is a variable. `a10 * s1a` is a linear expression. It does not evaluate as a number for the range expression.

You should look at basic CP-SAT example to understand how to access the value assigned to the variables after the solve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's great to get help from the creator of OR-Tools himself!

Comment: For me the problem is that I want the solver to maximise the number of successful items (like in the example in the second table above). This number depends on the processed date, which depends on the model variables. If I did this by hand, I would trial different values for the variables, then see which items got processed on which day, then work out the age and success rate, and repeat this process until I have the highest success rate out of all possible options. Would this be possible with OR-Tools?